# How to extract R sqr and adjusted R_squared in gmm estimation

Tags: r, mean, extract, gmm, rolling-computation

The below code perfectly provides my gmm estimates for 216 rolling windows.

```
    gmm_list <-  lapply(1:(length(ALLX$DE)-24), function(i) {
  tmp <- ALLX[i:(i+23),]
  DE <- as.matrix(as.numeric(tmp$DE))
  p <- nrow(DE) 
  rmrf_local <- as.matrix(as.numeric(tmp$rmrf_local))
  SMB_L <- as.matrix(as.numeric(tmp$SMB_L))
  HML_L <- as.matrix(as.numeric(tmp$HML_L))
  MOM_L <- as.matrix(as.numeric(tmp$MOM_L))
  bond_L <- as.matrix(as.numeric(tmp$bond_L))
  h <- cbind(rmrf_local,SMB_L,HML_L,MOM_L,bond_L)
  gmm(DE ~ rmrf_local+SMB_L+HML_L+bond_L, x=h)
})
```

I'm able to extract the coef (estimate, SE, t_value and P_value) with

```
lapply(gmm_list, function(x) coef(summary(x))[,1:4])
```

However, i am unable to extract the adj.Rsquared.

I used the code below but i have `NULL`, and any idea??

```
> sapply(gmm_list, function(x) summary(x) $r.squared)
  NULL
```

Comment: @Parfait Any idea?

Comment: @ theforestecologist Any comments please?

Comment: There is no reported R-squared for gmm objects. See yourself `summary.gmm(gmm_list[[1]])`.

Comment: @Parfait Do you think, if there could be a way to compute manually (R2)? I have seen a stackoverflow post, that tried to compute a standard error of a regression manually with a self made codes. Any idea?

Comment: You might use a "Pseudo R2". For OLS-estimated models with intercept, R2 can be calculated as R2 = cor(y_observed, y_fitted)^2 .... BTW, that's where the name R2 comes from. In gmm, R2 is not reported as Total Sum of Squares \neq Explained SS + Residual SS. However, the squared correlation between observed and fitted dep_var can be calculated and reported (one should point out what is being reported).